# How to populate a sockaddr_in from char* in a Linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I am experimenting with sendng UDP packets from a Linux kernel module following the example code at "[How to create a UDP Server in kernel-space](https://kernelnewbies.org/Simple_UDP_Server)"

I'm not that familiar with programming in kernel space.

In user space I can write:

```
struct sockaddr_in txAddr;
txAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.10");
```

But `inet_addr` does not appear available in the kernel.

How would I do it in the kernel space?

Comment: The Linux kernel runs on a freestanding C implementation, meaning that practically none of the C standard library is available to it.  It provides [its own versions of a variety of standard C functions, plus some that have no analog in the C standard library](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.7/core-api/index.html), but anything it does not provide, you need to write yourself or do without.

Comment: Supposing that your module's runtime configuration is controlled from userspace, consider doing conversions such as this on that side.  I mean, I assume you're not going to hardcode `"192.168.2.10"` into a kernel module, so why make the module deal with the address in that form at all?

Comment: Maybe `in4_pton`?

Comment: I want to put the address in the module as a first tiny step: send a packet.  Once that works the module's API will expand to set different parameters including the target address.  Normally I'd never hardcode an address in a module.

Comment: John, thanks for the link to the Core API.  I had read that previously and didn't find any networking stuff there, hence this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it manually:

```
txAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0x0a02a8c0;
```

Assuming your machine is little-endian, this will put the bytes in network byte order (i.e. big endian) in the field.